# Installing Foxit reader with wine

Tags: wine, foxit-reader, winetricks

Trying to install the latest Windows version of foxit reader (Linux app is not maintained), I get this error-

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking \njust-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.\n\n************** Exception Text **************\nSystem.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154)
  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR (System.Int32 errorCode) [0x0000a] in <373bec4b1e6c428eb4e9ef6a5beee544>:0 
  at System.__ComObject.CreateIUnknown (System.Type t) [0x00058] in <373bec4b1e6c428eb4e9ef6a5beee544>:0 
  at Mono.Interop.ComInteropProxy.CreateProxy (System.Type t) [0x00000] in <373bec4b1e6c428eb4e9ef6a5beee544>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.CreateClientProxyForComInterop (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <373bec4b1e6c428eb4e9ef6a5beee544>:0 
  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.ActivationServices.CreateProxyForType (System.Type type) [0x0003b] in <373bec4b1e6c428eb4e9ef6a5beee544>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters, System.Boolean wrapExceptions) [0x00005] in <373bec4b1e6c428eb4e9ef6a5beee544>:0
```

> \n************** Loaded Assemblies ************** \nmscorlib\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll\n----------------------------------------\nFoxit_Setup\n    Assembly Version: 11.1.0.52543\n    Win32 Version: 11.1.0.52543\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/home/vvasuki/Downloads/FoxitPDFReader111_Setup.exe\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Windows.Forms\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Drawing\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll\n----------------------------------------\nAccessibility\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: \n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/Accessibility/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Xml\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Configuration\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Configuration/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Core\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Web\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.0.0.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Xml.Linq\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Xml.Linq/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.Linq.dll\n----------------------------------------\nMono.Security\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.0.0.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/Mono.Security/4.0.0.0__0738eb9f132ed756/Mono.Security.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Web.ApplicationServices\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Web.ApplicationServices/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll\n----------------------------------------\nMicrosoft.VisualBasic\n    Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.17020\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/Microsoft.VisualBasic/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll\n----------------------------------------\nSystem.Numerics\n    Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0\n    Win32 Version: 4.6.57.0\n    CodeBase: file:///Z:/usr/share/wine/mono/wine-mono-6.3.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Numerics/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll\n----------------------------------------\n\n************** JIT Debugging **************\n

Any tips?